# Karma angular testing failed to instantiate module

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am just starting to set up some tests with Karma.  I some tests working with jdDom, but did not like how it was configuring.  However, I am not sure how to point to the js files correctly.  As I am getting this error

```
 Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ha.module.utility due to:
    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ha.module.utility' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I started a file with jsdom that required the core modules

require('../../../src/modules/core/module.core.built.js');
   require('../../../src/modules/utility/module.utility.built.js');

These scripts are where my modules reside.   I am not sure where to put them in the karma file.   **Or if this is even the issue** .  Here is my karma file below.  I removed the comments that come with karma init so it could be quicker to read on this post.

```
config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: 'Scripts/',

frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    'jquery /jquery libraries ',
    '../node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    '../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'test2/*.js',
    'tests/**/*.js'

],
exclude: [
    'tests/old/**',
    'tests/**/*.setup.js'
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
    '../Templates/**/*.html' : ['ng-html2js']
},

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
        // setting this option will create only a single module that contains templates
        // from all the files, so you can load them all with  angular.mock.module('foo')

        //stripPrefix: "Templates/",
        //prependPrefix: "Templates/",
        moduleName: 'templates'
    },

// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


port: 9876,

colors: true,


logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


autoWatch: true,



browsers: ['Chrome'],

singleRun: true,

concurrency: Infinity
```

Basically I need these tests to find the modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your modules' directives, controllers, and all other required files should be uploaded into your list of "files," like this:

```
files: [
    '../node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    '../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    '../../../src/modules/core/module.core.built.js',
    '../../../src/modules/utility/module.utility.built.js',
    'test2/*.js',
    'tests/**/*.js'

],
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense to put it in files.  Ideally I would put those before my tests correct?

Comment: Correct. For my Karma tests, I have all of my .js dependencies first, then my controller and directives, then the main app.module.js, then bringing up the rear are the tests.

Comment: Is this issue also feasible with ng2Html preprocessor?  I re-occured this error when I started the preprocessor and pointed to the Templates folder